# Selenium problem in VS Code Interactive Mode

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run Selenium from the interactive mode of Visual Studio code, but I am getting the error below. Everything works great in Jupyter or when I run the script non-interactively.

MRE

```
# %%
from selenium import webdriver    
url = 'google.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
```

Error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
++redacted++.py in 
      3 url = 'google.com'
----> 4 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
      5 driver.get(url)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, firefox_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
    168             executor = FirefoxRemoteConnection(
    169                 remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url)
--> 170             RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
    171                 self,
    172                 command_executor=executor,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 11
```

---

Edit 1:

Adding a screenshot of available environments

The first complain about ipykernel not being installed, even though it should be according to pip. The last two give the error

[image]

Comment: Please check whether the python environment you use in "Interactive" is what you want to use, and please try to reload VS Code and then open the new "Interactive" to run it. [Working with the Python Interactive window](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure which one I want to use. How do I figure it out?

Comment: -Usually, the default python environment used by "Interactive" is displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code, and the python used by it will be displayed above "Interactive", for example: "_Started'Python 3.8.3 64-bit ('.env01') 'kernel
Python 3.8.3..._"

Comment: What I have difficulty understanding/figuring out is what the correct environment should be. I have added a screenshot in my question above, because I don't know how to add pictures to comments

Comment: For the python environment in VS Code, you can refer to this document: [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: Sorry, but I am still not sure what exactly to do here to fix this. I read how to change the environment and tried all of them without success. I don't have an interactive option.